# No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, eclipse-juno

I'm getting an error..

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:545)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
at pack.ConnectionFactory.getConnect(ConnectionFactory.java:37)
```

```java
String DriverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static String url =     "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbqwe";
```

working with J2SE1.5,TOMCAT 6.0.36,MYSQL 5.5 SERVER and ECLIPSE JUNO.

```
tried with mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin
mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.2.jar
mysql-connector-java-3.1.7-bin.jar
ojdbc14.jar
```

Placed them in

```
web-inf/lib, tomcat lib
```

and

```
eclipse/jre/lib
```

added the jar file in to the java build path also...

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to supply `username` and `password` in your `String url`.

```
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbqwe?user=usrHere&password=passHERE";
```

for mire information on connecting `JAVA` with `MySQL`, visit the link below:

- [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

*PS: can you post your whole code?*

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your driver? Before `DriverManager.getConnection` there supposed to be

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

or

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ConnectionFactory 
    {
      String DriverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbb";
       static String Userid = "root";
     static String Pwd = "pswd";
      StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory(); 
     private ConnectionFactory()
{ try{ Class.forName(DriverClass);
     //output.append("Driver Installation Successful");
     System.out.println("Driver Installed"); }
 catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();
    output.append("Driver Installation Failed");  }}
  public  static Connection getConnect() throws SQLException 
  {Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, Userid, Pwd);
    return con;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this line is uncommented in ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
```

Change it to:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" driverManagerProtection="false" />
```

This returns Tomcat to pre-6.0.35 functionality, where it correctly registered the type 4 JDBC drivers in ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib